# Why am I getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" w/ my ArrayList?

Tags: arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am making a class to deal with a friend list scenario using an ArrayList and I'm not sure what I have done wrong. The "java.lang.NullPointerException" occurred the moment I called the addFriend method and I can't seem to troubleshoot exactly why this is happening. Please give me some hints in the right direction!

```
public class Person {
    private String name; 
    private ArrayList<String> friends;


    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void addFriend(String friend) {
        friends.add(friend);     
    }

    public boolean hasFriend(String name) {
        for(String friend : this.friends) {
            if(name.equals(friend)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;   
    }

    public String getFriends() {
        String stringOfFriends=friends.toString();
        return stringOfFriends;
    }

    public String unfriend(String friend) {
        if (friends.contains(friend)) {
            friends.remove(friend);
        }
    return friends.toString();    
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Constructor has to initialze the Arraylist:

```
public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

---

In your current version, you assign the ArrayList "friends" to itself. That means you basically call `this.frinds = this.friends` and this.friends is not initialzed yet hence the NullpointerException.

Comment: Accepting my awnser would be nice ;)

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor `this.friends = friends; doesn't make sense.` Make like this

```
 public Person(String name,ArrayList<String> friends) {
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = friends;
}
```

Then pass the actual arraylist to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your array list. Like `private ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();` or in the constructor as below:

`public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = new ArrayList<String>();
    }`